# How about an "ask a question about this" button?

Tags: feature-request

OK, so there are ubiquitous little twitter and facebook buttons anywhere.  It would seem like it would be a nice fit for SE to have a little [?] button people could use to link to a relevant SE, basically 'ask a formal question about this topic'. You could try to talk forum and blog folks into including it...

Edit: OK, adding a very amateurish mockup based on an RPG.net forum post. Again, a button just like the ubiquitous FB and Twitter buttons, and when you click it, it, like, comes to the site and [opens a new question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  In this case you'd probably be looking to ask a question about Paizo's Pathfinder supplement named Inner Sea Magic.  The only automatic thing that should probably be done is inclusion of a backlink in the opened question to the source as it'll probably be used for a reference.

Obviously not just for forums, but for "anywhere."  For product pages on a manufacturer's site or drivethrurpg. etc.

[image: Mockup]

Comment: +1 Very good idea indeed.

Comment: And inverting the idea, I wonder if there are any publishers who would be into directing FAQ traffic to here? Evil Hat pointing to http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dresden-files?

Comment: Has this concept evolved any in the past year? I rather like it

Comment: Haven't heard anything.